# Assign values to variable in c programming using a file

Tags: c, fgets, scanf

I want to read multiple variables from a single .txt file.

For example the following code will assign values to Txx,ST,mu,R0,DC and NB.

```
void main() {

    int Txx = 10;                       
    double ST = 0.07;                       
    double mu = 0.02;                       

    double R0 = 10e-6;                      
    double DC = 40e-6;                      
    int NB = 5;                     

}
```

Instead, is there a way to assign these values using a single text file which may be looks like this:

---

```
Txx = 10;                       
ST = 0.07;                      
mu = 0.02;                      
R0 = 10e-6;                     
DC = 40e-6;                     
NB = 5;
```

---

This might be a common problem. If you redirect me to a solution to this. It will be very helpful.

Thank you.

Comment: There's no built-in solution in C for this. You could either write your own code to do it, or google for "configuration file parser" etc. Using JSON is in vogue at the moment.

Comment: Do you want to be able to change the text file, rerun the executable and get a different result? If the text file contains an assignment to a variable that isn't in the code (e.g. `AB = 7;`), what should happen?

Comment: @MattMcNabb Thanks I will check JSON.

Comment: @Beta - yes, that's exactly what I am trying to do. The user will make sure that only the assigned variables are in the text file.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

enum Type { INT, DOUBLE };

struct var {
    char *name;
    void *pointer;
    enum Type type;
};

int search(struct var *vars, const char *name){
    int i;
    for(i=0; vars[i].name ; ++i){
        if(strcmp(vars[i].name, name)==0)
            return i;
    }
    return -1;//not found
}

int main(void){
    int Txx, NB;
    double ST, mu, R0, DC;
    struct var vars[] = {
        {"Txx", &Txx, INT},
        {"NB", &NB, INT},
        {"ST", &ST, DOUBLE},
        {"mu", &mu, DOUBLE},
        {"R0", &R0, DOUBLE},
        {"DC", &DC, DOUBLE},
        {NULL, NULL, 0}
    };
    FILE *fp = fopen("data.txt", "r");
    char buff[128];
    int i;

    while(1==fscanf(fp, "%s", buff)){
        if(-1!=(i=search(vars, buff))){
            if(vars[i].type == INT)
                fscanf(fp, " %*c %d;", (int*)vars[i].pointer);
            else if(vars[i].type == DOUBLE)
                fscanf(fp, " %*c %lf;", (double*)vars[i].pointer);
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);
    printf("Txx = %d\n", Txx);
    printf("ST  = %f\n", ST);
    printf("mu  = %f\n", mu);
    printf("R0  = %e\n", R0);
    printf("DC  = %e\n", DC);
    printf("NB  = %d\n", NB);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Crude, but effective:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
  int Txx, NB;
  float ST, mu, R0, DC;

  FILE *fp = fopen("single.txt", "r");

  char varname[60];
  char c;

  while(fscanf(fp, "%s %c", varname, &c) != EOF)
    {
      if(strcmp(varname, "Txx")==0)
        fscanf(fp, "%d%c", &Txx, &c);
      if(strcmp(varname, "ST")==0)
        fscanf(fp, "%f%c", &ST, &c);
      if(strcmp(varname, "mu")==0)
        fscanf(fp, "%f%c", &mu, &c);
      if(strcmp(varname, "R0")==0)
        fscanf(fp, "%f%c", &R0, &c);
      if(strcmp(varname, "DC")==0)
        fscanf(fp, "%f%c", &DC, &c);
      if(strcmp(varname, "NB")==0)
        fscanf(fp, "%d%c", &NB, &c);
    }

  printf("Txx %d\n", Txx);
  printf("ST %f\n", ST);
  printf("mu %f\n", mu);
  printf("R0 %f\n", R0);
  printf("DC %f\n", DC);
  printf("NB %d\n", NB);
  return(0);
}
```

Answer (score -3):

one thing you could do is load a text file using file stream and parse the texts in that file
As most of them said using Json would be a really good idea just incase if you are looking what is a json and how to validate it before you start using :

and to create your above list as json you just have to do this :

```
{
  "Txx" : 10,                       
  "ST" : 0.07,                      
  "mu" : 0.02,                      
  "R0" : 10e-6,                     
  "DC" : 40e-6,                     
  "NB" : 5 
}
```

[http://json.parser.online.fr/][1]

this will validate your Json file .

Comment: OP asked about C. Also, using end-of-file as a loop condition is a mistake in both languages, as the end-of-file indicator may not be set until you have already tried to read beyond the end of the file.

Comment: Thank you but I need a solution in C.

Comment: Reading a file does not seem to be the OPs problem; it's "is there a way to *assign* these values".